# Laravel Breeze logout redirect on 127.0.0.1 on shared host

Tags: laravel, breeze, logout

I have domain for example `aaa.com`. And I deploy Laravel on my webhost succesfully. Login, pages, all things etc. works fine. but whenever I logout it redirects me to `127.0.0.1` not `aaa.com`. Of course, I have to point out that I am using `Laravel Breeze`
and here is what I wrote:

my logout form inside any page.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
     @csrf

    <button type="submit" class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">
        {{ __('Log Out') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

My `web.php` include `require __DIR__.'/auth.php';` . Does not contain any logout redirects.

and inside `auth.php`

```
    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
->name('logout');
```

and finally `AuthenticatedSessionController.php`

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I don't understand why I am being redirected to `127.0.0.1` instead of `aaa.com`?

Edit:
and forgot to mention my `.env` file include

```
APP_URL=https://aaa.com
```

Comment: try to clean your config cache `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: where? in sharing hosting?

Comment: From ssh or from terminal if it exists

Answer (score 0):

In `.env` file, Change `APP_URL`

```
APP_URL=http://aaa.com
```

Comment: and I forgot to say, it already is.

Comment: Have you ensured that your APP_ENV=production ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who replied. It fixed itself the next day. It must be something left in the web host's cache, or your browser's. It's not a Laravel thing.